# CSS-3 Circulating a div horizontally around it's central point

Tags: css

Currently, I have following:

```
.loader_img { 
    margin: auto; display: block; position: relative; top: 31%; 
    -webkit-animation:spin 1s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation:spin 1s linear infinite;
    animation:spin 1s linear infinite;
}

@-moz-keyframes spin { 100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@-webkit-keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform:rotate(360deg); } }
```

And it is making the image circulate around it's centeral point i.e. like the following:

[image]

What I want is, to make the image circulate this way (i.e. horizontally around it's circular point)

[image]

I've been trying to achieve this but unable to do so. Can any one please tell me how may I make the image move around it's central point horizontally?

Fiddle for the current situation http://jsfiddle.net/5hfBH/1/

Comment: Do you have a fiddle of your current situation? And I don't really understand what you mean by 'horizontally around it's circular point. So you mean you want to image to move around a point, but not rotate itself? (stay upright))

Comment: @GolezTrol yes. Please check the question

Comment: Did you try the perspective property? http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_perspective.asp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `transform: rotatey(360deg)`.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2yHUy/)**

HTML

```
<div class="loader_img">A basic loader</div>
```

CSS

```
.loader_img {
    background: red;
    padding:10px;
    display:block;
    width:50px;
    margin:50px auto;
    -webkit-animation:spin 1s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation:spin 1s linear infinite;
    animation:spin 1s linear infinite;
}
@-moz-keyframes spin {
    100% {
        -moz-transform: rotatey(360deg);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotatey(360deg);
    }
}
@keyframes spin {
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotatey(360deg);
        transform:rotatey(360deg);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is using the `rotateY` transform property:

```
@-moz-keyframes spin { 100% { -moz-transform: rotateY(360deg); } }
@-webkit-keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg); } }
@keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg); transform:rotateY(360deg); } }
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/robertp/zeCbx/

What I think you mean by 'central point' is the transform origin point (`transform-origin`), which by default is centred but can be altered.

Here you can read more up on the CSS3 transforms:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transforms